# How to access element of <ng-template>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to access element by id which is inside the `<ng-template>` and I am showing that `<ng-template>` when loader is `false`. So in `subscribe` function after loader becomes `false` my  is renedering, and in subscribe method itself I am trying to access my 'gif-html' but I am getting it null

```
<div class="my-loader" *ngIf="loader; else show_form_content">
    <ngx-loading [show]="loader"></ngx-loading>
  </div>
  <ng-template #show_form_content>
   <div class="gifTimer" id="gif-html">
 
   </div>
  </ng-template>
 
 </div>

 getMyData() {
  this.loader = true;
  this.myService
    .getData()
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.loader = false;
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        let gifHtml = document.getElementById('gif-html');
        console.log('gifHtml', gifHtml)
      }
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getMyData()
}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Silvermind am I doing anything wrong? please suggest

Comment: When working with Angular, you should not resort to using document.getElementById. You are asking how to solve your `getElementById` problem and I'm wondering whether you actually want to know how to toggle the gif or some similar issue.

Comment: @Silvermind, I just wanted to apply some style which is inside the `id="gif-html"`, but I am not able to get that element after it renders, and same thing if I do with setTimeout then it is working, it means ng-template is not rendered while I am accessing in subscribe method

Answer (score 1):

getElementById method is returning null because the ng-template content is not rendered in the DOM when you're trying to access it.

The ng-template is a structural directive that doesn't render its content immediately. Instead, it serves as a template that can be rendered conditionally using the *ngIf or *ngTemplateOutlet directives.

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-loader" *ngIf="loader; else show_form_content">
  <ngx-loading [show]="loader"></ngx-loading>
</div>

<ng-template #show_form_content>
  <div class="gifTimer" id="gif-html">
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

I added the id="gif-html" template reference variable to the div element.

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';


export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('gif-html', { static: false }) gifHtmlRef!: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.getMyData();
    }

    getMyData() {
        this.loader = true;
        this.myService
          .getData()
          .subscribe((response) => {
            this.loader = false;
            if (response.status === 'success') {
              console.log('gifHtml', this.gifHtmlRef.nativeElement);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i hope it's help

Comment: getting error: `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')`, same answer I got from ChatGPT, and I tried the same solution, but it was not working for me

Comment: @techguy i update my answer please try again i think issue resolved

Comment: no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @techguy What issue you are facing ?

Comment: same eror: getting error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: did you create stackblitz link?